# Random Label value in a UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, random, uitextfield

I'm trying to make two UILabel randomly. The contents of the label are int I also try as soon as the input in the UITextField is correct to give the two UILabel new values. My question is: How can I send the UITextView the task as soon as the correct user input is entered, enter the new values ​​the two UILabel?

Here is the Action that i try to link to the UITextField.

```
- (IBAction)randomDef:(id)sender {
    int valueFromTextField = rand() % 100;

    int positiveNumber = 0;

    float x = ([firstNumber.text floatValue]);
    float y = ([secondNumber.text floatValue]);

    int ans = x + y;

    switch (valueFromTextField) {
        case 0:

            firstNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueFromTextField];
            secondNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueFromTextField];

            if (textField.text == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ans]) {

                positivePoints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", positiveNumber++];
                valueFromTextField++;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a notification like this

```
// Add a "textFieldDidChange" notification method to the text field control.
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

In your class you can implement `textFieldDidChange:` and move your code to the body of this function

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just wonder whether this switch-statement can work. Whether value from textField++, or as in the case 0:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol to respond to changes in a `UITextField`. Make your class conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, set `textfield.delegate`, then implement delegate methods such as `-textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `-textFieldDidEndEditing:`. If you want to respond to the user pressing the return key in the field, use `-textFieldShouldReturn:`.

[UITextFieldDelegate Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a)

Comment: Thank you! But what is -textFieldShouldReturn:.

Comment: `-textFieldShouldReturn` is a `UITextFieldDelegate` method that is called when a user taps return (usually after typing some value) in a textfield. So if you want them to type "20" and tap return, `-textFieldShouldReturn:` is called in response to the return key tap.